# SQL 2008 Update a value calculated from the previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

Table like this fields: ID, InvoiceDate, SystemEntryDate, InvoiceNo, GrossTotal, Hash.
For record with ID=1, the Hash is calculated with all fields from record 1, with the SignByAsymKey function.

For all other records (ID>2), the hash is calculated with same function SignByAsymKey, with all the fields from the record and the Hash from the previous record.

For example, for ID=3, the hash is calculated with the fields InvoiceDate, SystemEntryDate, InvoiceNo, GrossTotal, for that record, and with the Hash from record with ID=2.

How do I do this? Is it better to use a trigger or a Stored procedure?

I did a update trigger like this, but it gives the same hash to all records>1:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Invoice_update]
           ON  [dbo].[Invoice]
           AFTER update 
        AS 
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
update dbo.Invoice 
set [hash]=
    (Case
        when
            dbo.Invoice.ID=1
        Then
            SignByAsymKey (
            AsymKey_Id ('SecureAsymmetricKeyINVOICE'),
            CONVERT([nvarchar],(select [InvoiceDate] from Invoice where [ID]=1),0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],(select [SystemEntryDate] from Invoice where [ID]=1),0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],(select [InvoiceNo] from Invoice where [ID]=1),0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],(select [GrossTotal] from Invoice where [ID]=1),0)
            ,N'Portal2011!')
        else
            SignByAsymKey (
            AsymKey_Id ('SecureAsymmetricKeyINVOICE'),
            CONVERT([nvarchar],inserted.[InvoiceDate],0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],inserted.[SystemEntryDate],0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],inserted.[InvoiceNo],0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],inserted.[GrossTotal],0)+';'+
            CONVERT([nvarchar],
            (select [hash] from dbo.Invoice
            where [id]=inserted.id-1),0)
            ,N'Portal2011!')
    End)
from inserted
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with a trigger, as you know it will fire whenever any data is added/modified. It is harder to guarantee all data will be modified via the stored procedure.

Comment: but how to do this, i'm rookie in SQL. Can you post an code example?

Comment: @Hugo: There are many code examples of writing triggers for SQL Server on the web. Which part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: my difficulty is to refer the previous record to calculate the hash.